# How to create chat-like footer layout in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uwp, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms to create a chat-like app for Abdroid and UWP. I want to create a footer layout that looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUl2U.png)
(Meaning 2 buttons and an Editor in horizontal orientation).

I have created the layout in the image using the following xaml:

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="Android">5,0,5,5</On>
                <On Platform="Windows">5,0,5,25</On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Grid.Margin>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Editor x:Name="MessageText"  Text="" Grid.Column="0" />
        <local:RoundedButton x:Name="Button2" Clicked="click2"  BackgroundColor="#000000" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" BorderRadius="25" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <local:RoundedButton x:Name="Button1" Clicked="click1"  BackgroundColor="#000000" Grid.Column="2" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" BorderRadius="25" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem with this layout is that the Editor doesn't display fully more than one line. When I continue writing text that is longer than the Editor's width I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NEH3.png). As you can see the first line is cut-of and only the bottom of it is displayed when I start a new line.

As far as I know, it is pretty easy to create this kind of layout in Android using LinearLayout and the layout_weight attribute. But I try to avoid creating a renderer for the whole footer for now.

### Edit

Here is an example I wrote in Android with the wanted result:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Enter a message"/>
  <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="hi"/>
  <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="bi"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image: Wanted result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured this out in the end.

What Solved my problem was to put my CustomEditor inside a ScrollView.

So, this is the code that worked for me:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Grid.Margin>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="Android">5,0,5,5</On>
            <On Platform="Windows">5,0,5,25</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Grid.Margin>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollView>
        <local:RoundedEditor x:Name="MessageText"  Text="" Grid.Column="0" />
    </ScrollView>
    <Button x:Name="Button2"  BackgroundColor="#000000" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" BorderRadius="25" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Button x:Name="Button1" BackgroundColor="#000000" Grid.Column="2" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" BorderRadius="25" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

To grow the Editor when the text changes, you want to trigger the [InvalidateMeasure](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InvalidateMeasure/) method which will force the layout to resize. It's a protected method, so you need to subclass the Editor control and make the following change:

```
public class CustomEditor : Editor
{      
    public CustomEditor ()     
    {
        TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            InvalidateMeasure(); 
        };     
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, it helps for when I press enter to start a new line but it doesn't help if I just continue writing more characters than the width of the Editor(without pressing enter).

Comment: @JackPot16 I see, clicking Enter increases the size immediately while writing continuously only resizes the control periodically. It does get bigger but never fully shows all the lines. Not sure what's the problem yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "resize the control periodically"? I don't see it resizes at all. The problem is that I want to be able to see all the text that I entered and not only part of it, just like in whatsapp for instance.

Comment: @JackPot16 I wrote a small test app on Android. When I write in the editor and the text goes to the next line, the control doesn't resize instantly. Instead, it resizes only around the time I'm in the middle of the new line. When I press Enter, the control resizes immediately, as expected.

Comment: I have added my android test sample with the wanted result.

Comment: @handkie, Do you have any idea how can I create auch layout in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: @JackPot16, did you test this code? It should work for Android platform of XF, use this `CustomEditor` instead of your `Editor` in your layout.

Comment: Yes, I tested this code. It helps only in the case of pressing enter, when I just continue writing without pressing enter It doesn't resize. Does it work for you?

Comment: @handkie I figured out the solution, I needed to put this CustomEditor inside a ScrollView. I added the code as an additional answer.